# Escolher criptografia no SSL

Tags: java, socket, criptografia, ssl

Como eu posso definir exatamente qual criptografia vou usar na rotina abaixo?
Eu quero definir por exemplo que a criptografia a ser usada seja o AES, ou DES, ou 3DES...

```
// Setup truststore
KeyStore trustStore = null;
trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS"); 

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = null;
trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
InputStream trustStoreStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);

trustStore.load(trustStoreStream, "MyPassword".toCharArray());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

// Setup keystore
KeyStore keyStore = null;
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = null;
keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

InputStream keyStoreStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client);
keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "MyPassword".toCharArray());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "MyPassword".toCharArray());

ssl_ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ssl_ctx.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(),
        null);
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Disclaimer:** não sou especialista em segurança, nem tenho experiência prática com TLS em Java. Essa é uma resposta parcial, destinada a auxiliar na busca por uma resposta definitiva.

Em primeiro lugar, é bom notar que o AES/DES/3DES é apenas parte da equação: eles correspondem a uma primitiva criptográfica para cifragem simétrica. Sozinhos, são inúteis. De modo que um *"cipher suite"* é composto de várias primitivas distintas, como: 1) método de troca de chaves; 2) assinatura digital assimétrica; 3) cifragem simétrica - bloco; 4) cifragem simética - modo de operação; 5) hash. Se você executar o código abaixo, por exemplo, verá quais suites são suportadas (mas não necessariamente estão habilitadas) pelo seu Java:

```
SSLParameters params = ssl_ctx.getSupportedSSLParameters();
String[] suites = params.getCipherSuites();
for (int i = 0; i < suites.length; i++)
    System.out.println(suites[i]);
```

Exemplo de saída (varia conforme a implementação):

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
...
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
...
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
...
SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
...
```

<sub>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21289293/520779)</sub>

Como você pode ver, cada suite suportada pode usar SSL ou TLS, e para um mesmo algoritmo (`AES_128`, por exemplo) outros podem variar (ex.: RSA vs. Curvas Elípticas, SHA256 vs. SHA vs. MD5, etc). Em alguns casos nenhum algoritmo é empregado (ex.: `NULL` - faz com que a comunicação **não seja** confidencial), em outros se usa um que não está na sua lista (ex.: `RC4_128` ou `DES40`).

Eu não sei te responder como definir exatamente qual desses algoritmos utilizar. Se você quer colocar alguns deles numa "lista negra", uma maneira é usando a propriedade `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`, que já vem com alguns deles desabilitados por padrão:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
```

<sub>[Fonte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#DisabledAlgorithms)</sub>

Agora, se o que você quer é uma "lista branca" (ex.: pegar o array de algoritmos suportados e filtrar por aqueles que se encaixam nos seus critérios), é preciso descobrir exatamente em que ponto do código se deve fazer isso. *A princípio* isso poderia ser feito diretamente no [`SSLSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html), desde que antes do aperto-de-mão (*handshake*):

> Existem dois grupos de suites de criptografia que você precisará conhecer ao gerenciá-los:
>
> - Suites suportadas: todas as suites que são suportadas pela implementação do SSL. Esse lista é reportada usando `getSupportedCipherSuites`.
> - Suites habilitadas, que podem ser menos que a lista completa de suites suportadas. Esse grupo é atribuído usando o método `setEnabledCipherSuites` e recuperado usando o método `getEnabledCipherSuites`. Inicialmente, um conjunto padrão de suites será habilitado em um novo soquete que representa a configuração mínima sugerida.
>
> Os padrões de implementação exigem que apenas suites que autenticam servidores e provêem confidencialidade sejam habilitados por padrão. Apenas se ambos os lados explicitamente concordarem com comunicações sem autenticação e/ou não privadas (sem cifragem) é que tal suite será selecionada.
>
> Quando SSLSockets são inicialmente criados, nenhum aperto-de-mão é feito de modo que as aplicações podem primeiro atribuir suas preferências de comunicação: quais suites usar, se o soquete deve estar em modo cliente ou modo servidor, etc. Entretanto, a segurança é sempre garantida no momento em que dados da aplicação são enviadas através da conexão.

Isso sugere que essa propriedade pode ser atribuída diretamente no `SSLSocket`. [Essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13949097/520779) parece concordar com isso, mas não posso dar garantias quanto à sua correção (em particular, é importante saber se o aperto-de-mão já aconteceu ou não - e eu não sei como fazer isso, ou sequer se é possível).

Outra possibilidade é usar o construtor de [`SSLParameters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html) que recebe uma lista de suites. Onde usar esses parâmetros, também não sei te dizer (como já foi dito, não tenho experiência prática no assunto). Pode ser que seja no próprio soquete (através de [`setSSLParameters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setSSLParameters%28javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters%29) - nesse caso, fica a mesma ressalva que a outra sugestão acima), ou talvez exigir a criação de um [`SSLSocketFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) customizado, etc...